# Calculating datetime in SQL server with older dates from VBA Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a problem, which I cannot solve.

I did time calculations in a macro in MS Access. For example

```
format(datediff("n",Format(#2015-08-12 17:30:00#, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:nn"),Format(#2015-08-12 23:00:00#, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:nn"))/1440,"hh:nn")
```

gives `5:30` which is stored in a datetime-column in SQL SErver 2008R2 as 
`1899-12-30 05:30:00.000`.

Now I am transferring the calculation in a stored procedure and with

```
convert(time,'2015-08-12 23:00:00'-'2015-08-12 17:30:00')
```

I get a datetime value of `1900-01-01 05:30:00.000`.

I know that is the difference between VBA and SQL Server, but how can I solve it or even better how should I handle the already existing values?

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? A time? or a Date and a time? the time (5:30) is correct in both of your examples.

Comment: I Need only work time which are hours and minutes. This time multiplied with the hourly rate gives the salary.

Comment: The answer is correct in both scenarios, I do not see any problem unless you want to know why the different dates out of curiosity.

Comment: I Need only work time which are hours and minutes. This time multiplied with the hourly rate gives the salary.

The Problem is, that when first transfering the date from Access-Database to SQL-Server i defined the column as datetime and still filled the values from VBA.

Now I tried to Change the datatype to time(7) and when calculating 

    convert(float, workingtime)*wages*1440/60 as salary 

I get an error 'Explicit conversion from data type time to float is not allowed.'

So how shall I handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I do this:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(time, '2015-08-12 17:30:00')
```

I get:

> 17:30:00.0000000

This is a TIME datatype value, that can be used in a calculation, which is what I understand you are looking for.   If I have misunderstood, then your question isn't clear enough to me.

EDIT:

As for this question in your comment:

> Now I tried to Change the datatype to time(7) and when calculating
>   convert(float, workingtime)*wages*1440/60 as salary I get an error
>   'Explicit conversion from data type time to float is not allowed.' So
>   how shall I handle this issue?

To do this, instead of calculating a TIME datatype, you should get your date difference in minutes, and divide by 60:

```
CAST(DATEDIFF(minute,'2015-08-12 17:30:00','2015-08-12 23:00:00') AS float)/60.00)*wages*1440/60 as salary
```